# Adding Additional Currrencies to Product Price using wc_price Filter Hook

Tags: woocommerce, currency, price

Based on the answer from my original post [A non well formed numeric value encountered while using `wc_price` WooCommerce hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66084833/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-while-using-wc-price-woocommerce-hoo), I am now trying to add additional currencies to the function and finally, output them all.

**I decided to go with a DIV-section of four columns whereof the CSS makes it responsive.**

```
.exchanged-price{
float: left;
width: 25%;
padding: 15px;
}

.exchange-rate-wrapper:after{
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
.exchanged-price{
width: 50%;
}}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
.exchanged-price{
width: 100%;
}}
```

I then removed the use of the function, thinking I do not need it.

This is the new code, **which gives me the following error:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)
```

**This is the new code:**

```
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'filter_wc_price', 10, 5 );
function filter_wc_price( $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price, $original_price = null ) {

    // EUR
    $conversion_rate_eur = (float) 1.25;
    $symbol_eur = 'EUR';
    $currency_symbol_eur = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $symbol_eur );
    $euro_price = (float) $price * $conversion_rate_eur;
    // return number_format( $euro_price, 2, '.', '' );

    // US dollar
    $conversion_rate_us = (float) 0.85;
    $symbol_us = 'US';
    $currency_symbol_us = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $symbol_us );
    $us_price = (float) $price * $conversion_rate_us;
    // return number_format( $us_price, 2, '.', '' );

    // GP brittish pound
    $conversion_rate_gbp = (float) 1.35;
    $symbol_gbp = 'GBP';
    $currency_symbol_gbp = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $symbol_gbp );
    $us_price = (float) $price * $conversion_rate_us;
    // return number_format( $us_price, 2, '.', '' );


    $exchange_rate_section = '
    <div class="exchange-rate-wrapper">
        
        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2>' return number_format( $euro_price, 2, '.', '' ); '</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2>'return number_format( $us_price, 2, '.', '' ); '</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2>'return number_format( $gbp_price, 2, '.', '' ); '</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2></h2>
        </div>

    </div>';

    return $return . '<br>' . $exchange_rate_section;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors:

- You are writing PHP code along with other strings without using the string concatenation symbol `.` ([PHP: String Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)).
- The `$gbp_price` variable has not been initialized and/or valued.
- The symbol for getting the dollar currency is **`USD`** and not `US`.

So the correct function will be:

```
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'filter_wc_price', 10, 5 );
function filter_wc_price( $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price, $original_price = null ) {

    // EUR
    $conversion_rate_eur = (float) 1.25;
    $symbol_eur = 'EUR';
    $currency_symbol_eur = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $symbol_eur );
    $euro_price = (float) $price * $conversion_rate_eur;
    // return number_format( $euro_price, 2, '.', '' );

    // US dollar
    $conversion_rate_us = (float) 0.85;
    $symbol_us = 'USD';
    $currency_symbol_us = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $symbol_us );
    $us_price = (float) $price * $conversion_rate_us;
    // return number_format( $us_price, 2, '.', '' );

    // GP brittish pound
    $conversion_rate_gbp = (float) 1.35;
    $symbol_gbp = 'GBP';
    $currency_symbol_gbp = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $symbol_gbp );
    $gbp_price = (float) $price * $conversion_rate_us;
    // return number_format( $gbp_price, 2, '.', '' );


    $exchange_rate_section = '
    <div class="exchange-rate-wrapper">
        
        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2>' . number_format( $euro_price, 2, '.', '' ) . ' ' . $currency_symbol_eur . '</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2>'. number_format( $us_price, 2, '.', '' ) . ' ' . $currency_symbol_us . '</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2>' . number_format( $gbp_price, 2, '.', '' ) . ' ' . $currency_symbol_gbp . '</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2></h2>
        </div>

    </div>';

    return $return . '<br>' . $exchange_rate_section;
}
```

*The function has been tested and does not return errors.*

Comment: @HaroldAldersen Keep it up. Also try not to add spaces to the HTML code you post because it will be displayed (it is not ignored like PHP).