# Displaying Additional Currencies on WooCommerce Product Page based on Product Price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I realized that using `wc_price` is not a good way to go since it affects everything else in the system. So, I was hoping to make this work only on the product page without affecting the cart, checkout, minicart, admin orders, and everything else...

**So, based on [Adding Additional Currencies to Product Price using wc_price Filter Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106151/adding-additional-currrencies-to-product-price-using-wc-price-filter-hook) - This is my attempt in making that happen. The problem is; nothing is shown.**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'manual_currency_converter', 5, 1);
function manual_currency_converter($price) {

    $product = wc_get_product();
    $product_price = $product->get_price();

    // EUR
    $conversion_rate_eur = (float) 1.25;
    $symbol_eur = 'EUR';
    $currency_symbol_eur = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol($symbol_eur);
    $euro_price = (float) $product_price * $conversion_rate_eur;

    // US dollar
    $conversion_rate_us = (float) 0.85;
    $symbol_us = 'USD';
    $currency_symbol_us = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol($symbol_us);
    $us_price = (float) $product_price * $conversion_rate_us;

    // GP brittish pound
    $conversion_rate_gbp = (float) 1.35;
    $symbol_gbp = 'GBP';
    $currency_symbol_gbp = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol($symbol_gbp);
    $gbp_price = (float) $product_price * $conversion_rate_us;

    $exchange_rate_section = '
        <div class="exchange-rate-wrapper">
        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2>' . number_format( $euro_price, 2, '.', '' ) . ' ' . $currency_symbol_eur . '</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2>'. number_format( $us_price, 2, '.', '' ) . ' ' . $currency_symbol_us . '</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="exchanged-price">
        <h2>' . number_format( $gbp_price, 2, '.', '' ) . ' ' . $currency_symbol_gbp . '</h2>
        </div>
        </div>';

    return $price . '<br>' . $exchange_rate_section;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the `wc_price` filter hook, if you want the code to run on the single product page only then use [is_product()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-7) at the beginning of your function

So you get:

```php
function filter_wc_price( $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price, $original_price = null ) {
    // NOT true on a single product page, RETURN
    if ( ! is_product() ) return $return;
    
    // else continue.. my other code..

    return $return;
}
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'filter_wc_price', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. Must have done something weird before.